# Slice groupby.describe dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

[image]

I'd like to take all of the outer index, and only the mean and std from the inner index.

I attempted to use `idx = pd.IndexSlice` in the following ways:
`desc_df.loc[idx[:]]` yields the entire dataframe

`desc_df.loc[idx[3:4,:]]` yields only index 3 and 4

`desc_df.loc[idx[3:4,'mean']]` fails with `mean` is no in the columns

`desc_df.loc[idx[(3:4,'mean')]]` fails...etc

How do I execute my desired use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

df.loc[idx[:, ['mean', 'std']], :]
      #|   |       |            |
      #|   |       |            All columns    
      #|   |       |                
      #|   |      'mean' and 'std' locs of 1st level
      #|   |
      #|   Everything 0th level
      #|
      #Slice row index
```